# How to do static code inclusion in Javascript, using Grunt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, include, requirejs, gruntjs

I'm using grunt to compose a script that I have broken in two parts: `main.js` loads an inline worker, `worker.js` is the actual code for the inline worker.

And this means I have the following code to load the worker, inside `main.js`:

```
function setupWorker (workerCode) {
    var blobBuilder = new BlobBuilder();
    blobBuilder.append(workerCode);
    var blob = blobBuilder.getBlob('text/javascript');
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    return(url);
}

var workerURL = setupWorker('worker code, contents of worker.js');
var worker = new Worker(workerURL);
```

Now the question is, using Grunt, how can I substitute `'worker code, contents of worker.js'` in the example, with the actual contents of `worker.js` ?

Am I doing this right with static code inclusion ? Should I use one of the modules for require.js ?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with Grunt alone, you need modules. But why not create the new worker in `worker.js` anyway?

Comment: the problem is, which modules ? What's the strategy ? I don't create a new worker with `worker.js` because I wanted do distribute only one minified file instead of two.

Comment: As a side note, `BlobBuilder` is deprecated - you ought to use `var blob = new Blob([workerCode], {type: "text/javascript"});`.

Comment: Thanks @pimvdb, I've been meaning to update that for a while but I must study how older browsers will react to the change

Comment: You could process your .js files as templates, replacing variables with source code from other files but then you wouldn't be able to run your code without building it every time so I'm not sure this is a good way to go. requirejs is probably a better approach

Comment: How would you expect to be able to dynamically create workers in your app? You should probably share more information...